# Number of threads decreases as Parallel.Foreach loop goes on

Tags: multithreading, foreach, parallel-processing

I have a Parallel Foreach loop which loops through a list of items, and performs some actions against them.  Some of these actions take longer than others, depending on the item.

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, item =>
{
    var subItems = item.subItems;
    foreach (var subItem in subItems)
    {
        //do some actions for subItem
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Action Complete for {0}", item);
});
```

After a while, when there are only about 5-10 items left in the list to run, it seems that there is only 1 thread left running.  This is not ideal, because some items will then be stuck behind another one to finish.

If I stop the script, and then start it again, with only the leftover 5-10 items in the list, it spins up multiple threads to do each of the items in parallel again.

How can I ensure that the other threads will keep being used, without me needing to restart the script?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the default partitioner is blocking the work per task up into blocks of N `items`. It assumes that the number of items is large and each item takes the same amount of time then you would expect that the several threads will run the last ~ N * 5 items and all finish at the same time.

However in your case this is not true. You could write your own `Partitioner` to use a smaller number of items per block, See [Partitioner Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This may improve performance but it the work done per item is very small then you will increase the ratio of useful work to work done managing the tasks and possibly degrade performance.

You could also write a dynamic partitioner that decreases the partition size so that the last few items are in smaller partitions, thus ensuring that you are still using all the available threads. This MSDN article covers writing custom partitioners, [Custom Partitioners for PLINQ and TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for the same information since a long time.